# Update parts of a row in oracle with java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to be able to update parts of a row in a table in an oracle database. The database has a number (which is the primary key) and 5 other columns.

The method takes an object and compares it with the object with the same primary key in the database. It should then compare the columns and change those which are changed. I've thought of a few different ways of doing this:

- Perform a check for every single possible permutation of changes (long way of doing this).

For example:

```
    public boolean updateOrder(Order o, Connection con) {
    int rowUpdated = 0;
    String SQLString = "";
    Order origOrder = getOrder(o.getOno(), con);

    if (origOrder.getCustomerNo() != o.getCustomerNo()
            && origOrder.getEmployeeNo() == o.getEmployeeNo()
            && origOrder.getReceived().compareTo(o.getReceived()) == 0
            && origOrder.getBeginDate().compareTo(o.getBeginDate()) == 0
            && origOrder.getEndDate().compareTo(o.getEndDate()) == 0
            && origOrder.getProjectLocation().compareTo(o.getProjectLocation()) == 0) {

        SQLString = "UPDATE ORDERS SET "
                + "CNO = " + o.getCustomerNo()
                + "where ONO = " + o.getOno();

    }

    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    try {
        //== insert value----- Unit of work start
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = con.prepareStatement(SQLString);
        rowUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();

    etc...
```

- Just change everything every time (pretty simple, I'm afraid it might go wrong though).

Does anyone have a clever way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to perform the check for something that has changed? Just perform the update.

Comment: Why do you need to do the check first?  If you know the object is dirty, can't you just do an `UPDATE` where the primary key is equal?  Also, IMHO, using an ORM like Hibernate, and better yet JPA, is a much nicer way to handle reading/writting objects to/from a DB, and adds things like caching for performance.

Comment: That is not the way one should use prepared statements. You're also missing basic java naming conventions (SQLString!) ... and what's the deal with passing a connection for a public method as an argument?

Comment: @JamesB - Thanks for the input. I'd already considered it, I'll probably go with that.

Comment: @CodeChimp Thanks, I'll look into those. I'm still learning this stuff.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen I'm just following my teachers instruction.

Comment: @GeorgeWChubby, no problems.  We all started somewhere. And I am sure we have all wrote code that we wish we had not.  If this is for a class, scratch the ORMs...that's like advanced stuff you would do for a real app, not something for a class where you are learning.  Just keep plugging away, and keep asking questions.  Also, thanks for not asking "Can you do my homework for me?!?!?!", and instead asking "Here is what I tried, how do I make it work".  You will get many more answers here that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to perform the check for something that has changed? Just perform the update.

If you really need to make the check, push the comparison logic into a method of the Order class.

```
if(origOrder.hasChanged(o)) {
    // perform update
}
```

P.S. Variable names like o are not very meaningful or helpful.